# How do I fix session.user.id is returning null when I reload the page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase

This is my code

`

```
const session = useSession();
const supabase = useSupabaseClient();

useEffect(() => {
   
    supabase.from('profiles').select()
  .eq('id', session.user.id)
  .then(result => {
   if(result.data.length){
     setProfile(result.data[0])
     console.log(profile)
   }})
   
    
  },[]);
```

When I open the application, it works fine however when I try to reload the page, this error is returned: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYrdG.png). I am using next.js, react.

Comment: Just FYI, your `console.log(profile)` will not represent the data from `setProfile(result.data[0])` since the profile state will not have the updated value until the next render